# pandas split header cell into multiple header columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to work with pandas for a csv file. In the file the header row is in a single cell. The following rows are in multiple columns. I can't find an answer on how to split the string in the first row cell into multiple columns for the following row columns.

```
-----------------------------------------
|Time, Sensor ID, Value, Voltage        |
-----------------------------------------
|1.560380e+09|chan0    |-10306|0.009563 |
-----------------------------------------
|1.560380e+09|chan1    |7255  |0.310634 |
-----------------------------------------
|1.560380e+09|chan2    |-1294 |0.058111 |
-----------------------------------------
```

I am trying to split the first row to get:

```
-----------------------------------------
|Time        |Sensor ID|Value |Voltage  |
-----------------------------------------
|1.560380e+09|chan0    |-10306|0.009563 |
-----------------------------------------
|1.560380e+09|chan1    |7255  |0.310634 |
-----------------------------------------
|1.560380e+09|chan2    |-1294 |0.058111 |
-----------------------------------------
```

Any pointers is much apreciated!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[1:], columns=df.iloc[0].split(', ') )`?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
file = r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\split_header.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df.columns = df.columns[0].split(',')
df
```